# C# Trouble being able to subscribe to an event before it is instantiated. Used to update UI from other class

Tags: c#, oop

I am making a very simple RPG as a means to learn the language. As of right now, you press the explore button. this happens:

```
currentFight = new Combat();
currentFight.CombatStarted += new Combat.CombatStartedEventHandler(UpdateUI);
currentFight.StartCombat();
```

**Combat Constructor:**

```
public  Combat()
{
    Combatant = DatabaseLookUp.randGen();                
}
```

**StartCombat Function:**

```
public void StartCombat()
{
    OnCombatStarted();
}
```

**Event Code:**

```
public delegate void CombatStartedEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);
public event CombatStartedEventHandler CombatStarted;

protected virtual void OnCombatStarted()
{
    if (CombatStarted != null)
    // Checks if there are subscribers to the EnemyChanged event
    //'this' class is the one sending the event, and we do not want to send any additional data
    CombatStarted(this, EventArgs.Empty);       
}
```

The explore button instantiates a new Combat object. In the constructor of Combat.cs, it sets its own Current Enemy field = to the result of a random monster generator.

I only *then* can subscribe the update UI method to the combat. Then, I run the start combat method, that fires off the event (and will soon do other things).

The problem I have with this solution is that I would like to replace the `onExploreButtonClicked` code (above) with code that will run an event determiner function, that is called from a separate class. One of the options that the determiner can come up with is instantiating a new Combat object. With that object being called in a new class, I wont be able to subscribe to the event from right there.

I hope this question makes sense. Optimally, creating the new Combat object would have a line in the constructor to 'ping' the UI to either open a new form, change labels on the first form, or something similar. If I create the Combat object with no arguments, it will create a random monster. But, I also need to be able to give a parameter to the Combat object that will start the combat with a specific enemy.

Still very new to coding, so if this maybe doesn't make sense, I can send somebody some source code! Thank you guys!

Comment: Don't describe code, show the code.